# Python Scrape text from dynamically loading webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have written code using requests and BeautifulSoup in order to scrape a webpage.  But it turns out that the page loads dynamically using, I think, JS.  I have figured out a way to get the page to load the additional content  from within python using selenium. But in the chrome browser that is created through selenium, when I go to the page source, I don't see the new stuff that has been generated.  Do I need to abandon the requests+bs route and redo everything using selenium?

If so, how would I translate the following code into something Selenium could do?

```
h6s = soup.find_all('h6')
projecturls = []
for i in h6s:
    tempurl = i.find_all('a', href=True)[0]['href']
    projecturls.append(tempurl)
```

Comment: It is almost always easier to use their API to scrape the site. Open the network tab in Chrome and find out which endpoint they use to load the additional data.

Comment: Sorry - whose API?  And how do I go about using an API?  I haven't done this before.

Comment: Can you say which website you are using? @scandinavian_ says to press `F12` in Chrome, click on the Network tab, refresh the page, and see if you can glean any useful info from that.